# Parse a value and make it editable in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a requirement to parse a value in a field but also make it editable so that user can add a value by himself as well which is not dependent on calculation. I am able to parse the value to the field but I am not able to make it editable so that user add a value by himself. Please help.

```
var Height = document.getElementsByName('[Height]')[0].value;
var vertical = Height / 30;
if (vertical > 1) {
  var x = parseInt(vertical);
  console.log(x);
  document.getElementsByName('vertical')[0].value = x;
} else {
  return false;
}
```

Update

```
<input type="number" id="message" name="vertical" oninput="calculate()">
```

Comment: So which element are you trying to make editable? what is the HTML supporting this code?

Comment: share that code logic as well

Comment: How is the code supposed to know whether to divide the input by 30 or not?

Comment: Why don't you use `Input tag` and give the user to add any value?

Comment: Height is always divided by 30 to get the vertical variable. I have used the input tag on the vertical field but the requirement is it calculated based on height and if we need more vertical user can enter by himself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var heightInput = document.getElementById('height'),
  verticalOutput = document.getElementById('vertical');

function calculate() {
  var vertical = parseInt(heightInput.value,10) / 30;
  verticalOutput.value = vertical > 1 ? Math.floor(vertical) : "—";
}
```

```html
<div>Type in a value greater than 30</div>
<input type="number" id="height" oninput="calculate()">
=>
<input id="vertical" type="number" value="—">
```

In this solution, you have an input and output element. On every “oninput” the function will set the output field with the calculated value.

Comment: Then what exactly?

Comment: Type a number greater than 30 (otherwise nothing happens). This is how you presented your code. If not, what should happen?

Comment: So please type 90. The output value will be 3. Then you can click into the output field and write something totally different. Exactly what you described, isn’t it?